# SSMS 2012 can not load database

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, msdn

I got this error message when I tried to connect to SQL Server 2012 using Management studio 2012.

> Service 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IRegistrationService' not
>   found (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio)

Here is the step I got the error.
1. Launch SQL 2012 management studio
2. It asked for connect to database. Connect to a SQL 2012 server server

then it generated this error.

There is no add-on and I have been un-installing and re-installing. Doing the repair. Still has the error. We have the MSDN subscription, the version that we installed is SQL 2012 Developer version. On a side note, we are able to install this in a different server. The only different between this two servers is that one is runing Windows 2008 Enterprise (R2 sp1), and the other is Windows 2008 Standard. Windows 2008 Enterprise has issue.

One thing thought, whenever I run the management studio 2012, it gave me "user account control" warming, "Do you want to allow the following program to make change to the computer". I didn't have this warming when running management studio 2008. Thanks,

Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: Please check if you have **Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio.dll** in **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE** If not, check the windows event log for install errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it as an administrator on your computer to not get these errors. Also you have to update any add-ons that you have on SSMS 2008 or you will continue to get this error. Do you have any add-ons currently installed?

Answer (score 0):

Go the error from a broken ie: I had moved by mistake "program files (x86)\Internet Explorer" in a random neighbor folder.

Hope it can help someone as unlucky as I was: check if you can run ie, however far this sound from SQL Server.

The messages went off as I fixed ie.